# Allowed memory size of 419430400 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 40961 bytes) in Symfony propel 1.3

Tags: memory, symfony1, propel

I'm using symfony propel 1.3 i'm uploadinga csv file to add user my file has 1500 lines(users)
and i'm inserting into some 10 tables when i'm using the propel code i'm getting the 
Allowed memory size of 419430400 bytes exhausted(tried to allocate 40961 bytes) but in normal php code it's executing completely so how to solve this error, how can we free the space in symfony propel

Comment: Have you run an xDebug trace to see what is taking all the memory?  Also are you running php 5.3.x?  Have you tried, if you're in a loop, setting variables you don't need anymore to `null` to hint to the garbage collector to recover memory?  Unless you're using an unpatched version of symfony the memory leak is probably in your code.  Have you tried upgrading to the latest version of 1.4 to test if the memory leak goes away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this prblem but with doctrine (!). Maybe there is something similar for propel. I fixed it with the following code:

```
$user->save();
$user->free(true);
unset($user);
```